# Prove or refute that $\log_5(0.7-2^x)=\log_2(0.7-5^x)$ if and only if $x=-1$

Tags: calculus

I have been trying to prove that the following two functions intersect at a single point $(-1,-1)$:

- $f(x)=\log_5(0.7-2^x)$
- $g(x)=\log_2(0.7-5^x)$

It is sufficient to prove that:

- If $x>-1$, then $g(x)>f(x)$
- If $x<-1$, then $g(x)<f(x)$

I believe it should be relatively easy to prove that they don't have more than two intersection points (though I fail to see how this might help in proving that they only have a single intersection point).

Can anyone help proving or refuting that?

Here is the graph of both functions:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove that $f'<g'$:

\begin{align}f'(x)<g'(x)&\iff-\frac{2^x}{.7-2^x}\frac{\log2}{\log5}<-\frac{5^x}{.7-5^x}\frac{\log5}{\log2}\\
&\iff\frac{2^x}{.7-2^x}\frac{.7-5^x}{5^x}>\frac{\log^25}{\log^22}=:k\\
&\iff\frac{.7\cdot5^{-x}-1}{.7\cdot2^{-x}-1}>k\\
&\iff(.7\cdot5^{-x}-1)>(.7\cdot2^{-x}-1)k\\
&\iff2^{-x}k-5^{-x}<\frac{10}7(k-1)\\
\end{align}

Thus we are showing that $h(x):=2^{-x}k-5^{-x}$ has a particular upper bound. Since it is a difference of exponentials, we already know it has one root and is upper bounded. The derivative $h'(x)=2^{-x}k\log 2-5^{-x}\log 5$, which is zero when $x=x^\circ:=-\log_{5/2}\log_25$. Then $$h(x)\le 2^{-x^\circ}k-5^{-x^\circ}\approx5.805<6.273\approx\frac{10}7(k-1).$$

(Sorry I had to resort to numerical evaluations, but this *is* a rigorous proof, since with a good enough evaluation of the two constants you can bound one above the other.)

Comment: I believe that If $x>-1$, then $f'(x)>g'(x)$.

Comment: @barak Nope; for $x<\log_2.7$ (implicitly assumed above - this is the domain of $f(x)$), $f'<g'$ (i.e. on either side of $-1$), at least according to the graph and the proof above. And that's what we want; if it was $f'>g'$ on the other side, the graphs of $f$ and $g$ would touch, but not pass through each other.

Comment: You can see this on your own graph; $f(x)$ is the upper function on the far left, and the lower function on the right. The derivative of $f$ is *more negative* on both sides of $-1$.

Comment: Oh, exactly. That's what's been baffling me, as I kept thinking that $f$ was decreasing faster "on the left of $-1$" and $g$ was decreasing faster "on the right of $-1$"!!!

Answer (score -1):

Let $f(x) = \log_5(0.7-2^x)-\log_2(0.7-5^x)$; $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable for $x<\log_2(0.7)\approx-0.51$, so you can apply *Rolle's Theorem*. By absurd, suppose there exist two numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$, such that $F(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$, then by the *Rolle's Theorem*, there exists a number $c$ in $]x_1;x_2[$, such that $f'(c)=\frac{2^c\ln(2)}{(2^c-0.7)\ln(5)}-\frac{5^c\ln(5)}{(5^c-0.7)\ln(2)}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{2^c\ln(2)}{(2^c-0.7)\ln(5)}=\frac{5^c\ln(5)}{(5^c-0.7)\ln(2)}$ but this equation [has no real solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20for%20c%20real%20%2810%5Ec-2%5Ec%2a0.7%29%28ln2%29%5E2=%2810%5Ec-5%5Ec%2a0.7%29%28ln5%29%5E2)! *Absurd conclusion* $\to$ there is only 1 solution $(x=-1)$.

Comment: I think the issue is showing that that equation has no solution.

Comment: I don't see how *WolframAlpha* can be considered as a mathematical proof. I could just as well take the original functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and show on *WolframAlpha* that $x=-1$ is the only solution to the equation $f(x)=g(x)$. The answer is not that bad though, so I don't understand why it was down-voted.

Comment: Also, for the record, this kind of equation is not amenable to solution by Mathematica's *Solve* function, so even if it did have a solution Mathematica wouldn't be able to give a closed form for it.

Comment: Hi @Mario Carneiro. This question is in relation with my previous question, to which you gave an answer.

Comment: so I'm trying to prove the absence of solutions...

Comment: @barak Yep, that's how I got here (you piqued my interest)

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: I believe it should be relatively easy to prove that they don't have more than two intersection points (though I fail to see how this might help in proving that they only have a single intersection point).

Comment: @barakmanos Actually, that's easy: since $f=g^{-1}$, if there is an intersection at $(x,y)$ there is also one at $(y,x)$.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: So how does that prove that they don't have more than two intersection points? And what do you mean $f = g^{-1}$?

Comment: @barakmanos Didn't you notice from the graph that they are mirror images? If $f(x)=y$, then $g(y)=x$.

Comment: @barak It doesn't prove they have at most two intersection points; but it does prove that they have an odd number of intersections, since the intersections come in pairs, except for $(-1,-1)$. So if you could prove there were at most two, there must be only one, and you've already found one.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: Oh, OK, got it.